# Properties Not Available In Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

The date object in `dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);` or anything else isn't available in the constructor as it's not been set. Would the only way around this be set all of these in the constructor?

```
 public class BorrowedItemModel
    {
    public String _id { get; set; }
    public String issuer { get; set; }
    public String issued { get; set; }
    public String issuedname { get; set; }
    public String obj { get; set; }
    public String date { get; set; }
    private DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan timeleft { get; set; }
    public string TimeLeftString { get; set; }
    private Timer timer;

    public BorrowedItemModel()
    {
        timer = new Timer(1000*60);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
        timeleft = dateTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timeleft = timeleft.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        TimeLeftString = timeleft.ToString();
    }
}
// where this is called in another class // 

 model = new BorrowedItemModel { _id = value["_id"].ToString(), date = value["date"].ToString(), issuer = value["issuer"].ToString(), issued = value["issued"].ToString(), issuedname = value["issuedname"].ToString(), obj = value["obj"].ToString() };
```

Comment: Why do you have separate properties for `date` and `dateTime` at all? If they're meant to be related, just have a single property - or if you *really* need to, have two properties that use a common field. I'd also strongly recommend that you read up and follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: There are multiple ways to approach your specific concern, but I agree that the most obvious is to not set the `dateTime` property in the first place; just define it as `private DateTime dateTime => DateTime.Parse(date);`. This will avoid the other bug you have, which is that you could set the `date` or `dateTime` property later and then the two would be out of sync. Unfortunately, your question is too broad to know what _you_ would want best as an answer.

Comment: The syntax you are using is an object initializer. It calls the constructor FIRST and THEN assigns the properties on the new object. Perhaps add parameters to your constructor instead if you wish date to be processed within it (though I agree with computed properties for dateTime and timeleft and following naming conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your date property to update your dateTime property

```
public class BorrowedItemModel
    {
    public String _id { get; set; }
    public String issuer { get; set; }
    public String issued { get; set; }
    public String issuedname { get; set; }
    public String obj { get; set; }
    private String _date;
    public String date 
    { get {return _date;} 
      set 
      {
        _date=value;
        dateTime = DateTime.Parse(value);
        timeleft = dateTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
      }
    }
    private DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan timeleft { get; set; }
    public string TimeLeftString { get; set; }
    private Timer timer;

    public BorrowedItemModel()
    {
        timer = new Timer(1000*60);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        //dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
        //timeleft = dateTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

}
```